# xeon processor super slow with windows 10 clean install

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance

So I have a machine that was a windows 7 machine with Xeon processor (3.6 Ghz), 16 Gig memory.  We upgraded it to Windows 10.   It was performing terribly slow after upgrade, so I figure possibly some upgrade issues or virus problems.

After doing some scans, cleanup, etc. and still having issues.  I wiped it and did a clean windows 10 install.

Still super slow performance for my user, even though the performance monitor does not seem to be going crazy.  Lags, slow response, etc.

A new cheap all in one with 4G memory is running circles around it.

I tried a lot of the "Windows 10 super slow" tricks and tips:  Tweak paging, turn off cortana, etc.  Still slow.

I'm stumped.  We are taking the machine out of production, but I'm bugged by WHY windows 10 is crawling on a machine with plenty of juice.

Ideas?

Comment: How do you concluse it is crawling? Are CPU bound program running slow? Is diskIO slow? Or is the machine blazingly fast and are just the screenupdates slow (e.g. when there are no graphics drivers installed). More data is needed.

Comment: Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Seems to slow down terribly using a cloud based program (Remote Desktop)... however the NIC card is a gig connection and I've bypassed any extra switches to make a direct route to the router.  Additionally I don't get drops of any sort when I do a ping -t hitting the secure server...